# Apps using Google Wave

Tags: api, google-wave

I just watched Google Wave Keynote video on Google I/O and I must say I was very impressed with pretty much everything mentioned in the video, the possibilities with Google Wave are enormous.

I'd like to ask if there are any projects using Google Wave already in beta (usable stage) and I would also like to know when is Google Wave supposed to be available for the rest of us who didn't attend Google I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As great as the technology is. It is safe to say it will only be used to find more inventive ways for us to:

1. Not socialize in real-life
2. Make communications that would be ill-advised in real-life
3. Buy things we haven't seen in real life
4. Unlearn things that are useful in real life (like spelling)

Joking aside, you can signup for the sandbox (as I have) and play around with apps and robots and whatever. You can [Sign up here](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/wavesignupfordev/) for the developer preview and have a look at what is going on!

You could also run your own wave setup using the [information here](http://waveprotocol.org/) and experiment with the down-and-dirty!

Comment: +1 but you forgot "inflate our egos with the sense that only we understand this new technology".

Comment: What, Google Wave isn't new? They seem to be marketing it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can request developer access to the wave sandbox at: https://services.google.com/fb/forms/wavesignupfordev/

It might take a few weeks.