# Google Wave Context-Aware Spell Checker

Tags: web-services, api, nlp, spell-checking, google-wave

Is it possible to use the [Google Wave Context-Aware Spell Checker](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/05/googles-context-sensitive-spell-checker.html) via web services?

If yes, can anyone please be kind enough to post a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Wave hasn't been released yet.

Comment: You can watch a video of a presentation they made about it. They told the audience (just those physically present) that they'd get accounts on their sandbox server, but afaik the general population has no access to the system, or any code for it.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357110/apps-using-google-wave and this https://services.google.com/fb/forms/wavesignupfordev/